# Checking a list of string variables is a particular string

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list of string

```
[a,b,c]
```

How do I check if all the variables are the string 'Ready'?.

I want to return True if all variables are `Ready` else False.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `all` and a list comprehension:

```
lst = ['Ready', 'Ready', 'Ready']
print(all(i == 'Ready' for i in lst))
```

Output:

```
True
```

Thanks for @schwobaseggl's comment, you can also do this:

```
print(all(map("Ready".__eq__, lst)))
```

Comment: Note that you do not have to build list with booleans in order to use all, i.e. you might do: `print(all(i == 'Ready' for i in lst))`.

Comment: Yup, you should really use `all` with a generator, not a list comprehension.

Comment: @schwobaseggl Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060653/list-comprehension-without-in-python/9061024#9061024

Comment: @Daweo Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060653/list-comprehension-without-in-python/9061024#9061024

Comment: Agree... but is a nice answer , just remove `[]`

Comment: @adirabargil Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060653/list-comprehension-without-in-python/9061024#9061024

Comment: @U11-Forward Yup but that is a special case for `str.join` where all elements will always be needed and the space for the final string needs to be allocated. `all`'s big advantage is the short-circuit (it can stop on the first non-"Ready") which you negate by building a list of booleans for all elements.

Comment: @schwobaseggl True maybe i change it now:

Comment: That is not true for the `all` function  at all... try timeit this: `all( not i==0 for i in range (10000))` vs `all([ not i==0 for i in range (10000)])`

Comment: Talking performance, one could argue that `all(map("Ready".__eq__, lst))` is even better as it won't have to repeatedly lookup the `__eq__` method on a different `str` object.